# Weird behavior when hiding & showing list elements in accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, bootstrap-typeahead

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyuYB/) from the problematic part of my website.

As I tried writing the code:

Typing some letters to the field will list names using typeahead, and when any of the elements are clicked in the typeahead dropdown, the accordions that does not have a `<li>` inside which contains the search will hide, and the ones that do have a `<li>` in them which's content matches the search, only the matched `<li>`s should be displayed, the others should hide.

Right now, all of the `<li>` will show, even if they do not contain the search.

I tried fixing it, but simply cannot find my way to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code I modified it to this. 
After you show the LI's you want to search the list of shown ones and hide any children that do not meet the contains selector criteria

http://jsfiddle.net/jyuYB/10/ demo

changed code:

```
$('#findname').typeahead({
    source: namelist,
    updater: function(item) {
        $('#ponies .accordion-group').show();
        $('#ponies .accordion-body li:not(:contains(' + item + '))').parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
        $('#ponies .accordion-body li:contains(' + item + ')').parent().parent().parent().parent().show();
        $('#ponies .accordion-body li:contains(' + item + ')').parent().parent().parent().addClass('in');
        $('#ponies .accordion-body li').hide();
        var tmp = $('#ponies .accordion-body li:contains(' + item + ')').show();
        tmp.each(function() {
            $(this).siblings().each(function(){ $.hide() });
        });
        return item;
    },
})
```

Comment: Looking at the console, I just noticed jQuery throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`. Until this is solved, I'm taking back the green tick.

Comment: Managed to fix the error using `$(this).siblings().each(function(){$(this).hide()});`, edit suggested.